# Unable to redirect a user to a desired page after login with Spring Security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

Everything works fine in this web application. The browser is prevented to cache pages. Login & logout works too. After logout, I am able to sucessfully redirect the user to the login page.

The flow of the web application control can be illustrated by this simple flow diagram.

> ***> loginForm  >  a  >  b  >  c  >  registerForm  >  profile***

these are the basic 6 pages in the applcn.

***loginForm.jsp :***

```
<body onload='document.f.username.focus();'>
    <h3>Login with Username & Password</h3>
    <form name='f' method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" value='' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input name='submit' type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" 
                                         value="${_csrf.token}">
            </td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

***a.jsp:***

```
<h1>Your Profile - a</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}">
    </form>
```

***b.jsp:***

```
<h1>Your Profile - b</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}">
    </form>
```

***c.jsp:***

```
<h1>Your Profile - c</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}">
    </form>
```

***registerForm.jsp:***

```
<form method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="firstName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lastName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="userName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td><input type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}">
    </form>
```

***profile.jsp:*** contains the ***logout*** link also.

```
<h1><a href="#" onclick="javascript:logoutForm.submit();">logout</a></h1>

        <c:url var="logoutUrl" value="/logout" />
        <form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post" id="logoutForm">
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                value="${_csrf.token}" />
        </form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name:</td>
            <td><c:out value="${spitter.firstName}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name:</td>
            <td><c:out value="${spitter.lastName}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name:</td>
            <td><c:out value="${spitter.userName}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

***LoginController.java***

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLoginForm() {

        System.out.println("Inside GET loginPage");

        return "loginForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginPage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processLoginForm() {

        System.out.println("Inside POST loginPage");
        return "redirect:/spitter/a";
    }
}
```

The first method gets called when I request the ***loginForm.jsp*** by typing

> http://localhost:8080/web/loginPage

When I click the ***submit button*** on ***loginForm.jsp***, it should have resulted in calling the ***second method*** present in ***LoginController.java***. However, this never happens. ***Why?***. I see sometimes It is ***redirected*** to the ***profile.jsp*** or ***othertimes the URL in the browser bar*** is reflected as

> http://localhost:8080/web/

which is ***HTTP Status 404 - /web/***

Other controller:

***SpittrController.java:***

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/spitter")
public class SpittrController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/a", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String a() {

        return "a";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/a", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processA() {

        return "redirect:/spitter/b";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/b", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String b() {

        return "b";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/b", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processB() {

        return "redirect:/spitter/c";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/c", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String c() {

        return "c";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/c", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processC() {

        return "redirect:/spitter/register";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showRegistrationForm() {

        return "registerForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processingRegistration(@Valid Spitter spitter, Errors errors) {

        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "registerForm";
        }

        spittleRepository.save(spitter);
        return "redirect:/spitter/" + spitter.getUserName();

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{username}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showSpitterProfile(@PathVariable("username") String username,
                                     Model model) {

        Spitter spitter = spittleRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (spitter != null) {
            model.addAttribute(spitter);
        }

        return "profile";
    }
}
```

***Java Configuration to enable spring MVC web security:***

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig
    extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.formLogin().loginPage("/loginPage").and()

            .authorizeRequests()

            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/spitter/a").authenticated()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/spitter/a").authenticated()

            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/spitter/b").authenticated()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/spitter/b").authenticated()

            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/spitter/c").authenticated()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/spitter/c").authenticated()

            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/spitter/register").authenticated()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/spitter/register").authenticated()

            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/spitter/**").authenticated()



            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/loginPage");

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password")
            .roles("USER").and().withUser("admin").password("password")
            .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

}
```

***Eclipse structure of the applcn:***

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `http.formLogin().loginPage("/loginPage").defaultSuccessUrl("/spitter/a").and()‌​.` in web security configuration.

Comment: You gave me a hint. Even though the correct answer is **http.formLogin().loginPage("/loginPage").defaultSuccessUrl("/spitter/a").and()**. Edit it and then i will mark your answer as accepted, as you gave me a hint. Thank you very very much indeed.